# How can I use the Azure speaker recognition API in C#?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-services, speaker

I am a student doing a voice-related project with C#.

I already used Azure Bing Speech API and Google Cloud Speech API to get people's voice as text.

But I also need Azure Speaker Recognition API to identify and verify an individual speaker using voice.

However, there isn't much information about this API even though Google Searching. And the Azure site (especially, the part that identifies and verifies speaker using wav file containing the user's voice) is so simple...

I don't know how to load a wav file to identify and verify speaker in C# code.

How can I do that using the Azure Speaker Recognition API?

What I have tried:

Following is sample code on the [Azure Site](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563309b6778daf02acc0a508/operations/5645c725ca73070ee8845bd6).

```
static async void MakeRequest()
{

    var client = new HttpClient();
    var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

    // Request headers
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "subscription-key");

    // Request parameters
     queryString["shortAudio"] = "true";

    var uri = "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/spid/v1.0/identify?identificationProfileIds={identificationProfileIds}&" + queryString;

    HttpResponseMessage response;

    // Request body
    byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{body}");

    using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
    {
        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

        response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For code snippets on the Azure site, you always need to substitute the placeholders of the form `{something}`, so in your case you need to fill in the appropriate values for `identificationProfileIds` and `body`.  Furthermore, the content-type needs to be either `application/octet-stream` or `multipart/form-data`, not `application/json`.

You'll save a good deal of typing by using the pre-built client [SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ProjectOxford.SpeakerRecognition/) instead.  You may also look at the source code for that SDK, for example [IdentifyAsync](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-SpeakerRecognition-Windows/blob/master/ClientLibrary/SpeakerIdentificationServiceClient.cs#L202), on how the HTTP request is constructed.

Comment: Yes. That code is just sample code from the Azure site.
And I eventually used the Speaker Recognition API.
I read the readme on https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-SpeakerRecognition-Windows and applied the example.
thank you.

Comment: @cthrash this is not available in .net core, and i dont want to send identificationProfileIds. Is it possible

Comment: The aforementioned github [site](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-SpeakerRecognition-Windows) has the .NET Framework source for the library, and I suspect you could recompile for .NET core without too much effort.  A quick search didn't yield a premade one.